# Prove the set $\left\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n : 0 < x_i < 1, 1\leq i \leq n\right\}$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm having a lot of difficulty with proving the set $S = \left\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2 : 0 < x_1,x_2 < 1\right\}$ is open. I need to use the definition of an open set to prove this. At this point I mostly have "scratch work."

For any $\vec{a}\in S$,  $\Vert \vec{a}\Vert < 2$ since each component of the vector is between $0$ and $1$.

Let $\vec{y},\vec{a}\in S$ and let $r = 2-\Vert\vec{a}-\vec{y}\Vert>0$. If $\vec{x} \in B_r(\vec{a})$, then 
$$\Vert\vec{x}-\vec{y}\Vert \leq \Vert\vec{x}-\vec{a}\Vert + \Vert\vec{a}-\vec{y}\Vert <2.$$

Thus $|x_1-y_1|-|x_2-y_2| \leq \Vert(x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2)\Vert<2$.

I have a hunch this is not the radius I should be using for the ball, but I'm not sure how to properly go about this problem.

Comment: what metric are you using?

Comment: Euclidean metric

Comment: All norms are equivalent on finite dimensional vector spaces, and as you want each component of the vector to have mod less than 1, use the sup (max) norm, then the norm of an arbitrary vector in your set would be $c$ for some $c < 1$ then a ball of radius $r<1-c$ should work?

Comment: Your attempted argument is confusing because you use $a,y,x$ without telling what they are supposed to mean. For example, it seems that $a$ is any point in $S$ and you want to prove that some ball around it is still in $S$. But I can't figure out what you need $y$ for, and how it is determined.

Comment: y and a are both in S, as stated. I was playing around with the triangle inequality to see if I could get somewhere useful. I tried googling what the sup (max) norm is but I'm still a bit confused. For reference, this is for a real analysis course covering the basics about topology of R^n.

Comment: @moofasa how fimiliar are you with product topologies?

Comment: @Riquelme, i only know that it R^n, the euclidean topology, is a product topology of R n times. otherwise my knowledge is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $(a,b) \in (0,1)×(0,1)$;

$d_x:= \min (1-a,a)$; $d_y:= \min (1-b,b)$;

$r:=\min (d_x,d_y).$

$B_r(a,b)= $

{$(x,y)| \sqrt{(x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2}<r$}.

$(x,y) \in B_r(a,b)$ implies

$|x-a| < r \le d_x$, and $|y-b| <r \le d_y$, hence

$B_r(a,b) \subset (0,1)×(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume (a,b) in S = [0,1]^2.
Let r > 0 be less than a, 1-a, b, and 1-b.
Show B((a,b),r) is a subset of S.  (Euclidean metric)
Thus, as every point of S is inside an open subset S, S is open.

Alternatively, show S is the union of all the above described balls and conclude that as S is a union of open sets, it is open.

Comment: I'm not seeing how to relate these balls to showing that (x,y) in B((a,b),r) => 0<x<1 and 0<y<1.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Show that if $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\in S$, then by defining $$y=(y_1,y_2,\cdots , y_n)\\|y_i-x_i|<\epsilon$$$y$ will also belong to $S$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Maybe I am overthinking this, but I don't see how showing that the distance is smaller than epsilon argues that $\vec{y}$ has components that are each between 0 and 1. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. If any $x_i$ falls within $(0,1)$, then by definition $$x_i-\epsilon<y_i<x_i+\epsilon$$and you can choose $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small such that $$0<x_i-\epsilon<y_i<x_i+\epsilon<1$$this is because from $$0<u<1$$one can choose some $\epsilon>0$ such that$$\epsilon<u<1-\epsilon$$